# How can i access previous value of a variable?

Tags: c#

I want to access previous value of global variable "i".
Here is my code.

```
int i = 0;
    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open) { con.Close(); }
        try
        {

            con.Open();
            i++;
            //int i2=i-1;
            String s = "insert into Add_Information values('"+i +"','"+ txtCompanyName.Text + "','" + txtOffAddress1.Text + "','" + txtOffAddress2.Text + "','" + txtCityAndPin.Text + "','" + txtContactPersonName.Text + "','" + txtDesignation.Text + "'," + txtOffPhoneNo.Text + "," + txtFaxNo.Text + "," + txtMobileNo.Text + ",'" + txtOfficialEmailId.Text + "','" + txtPersonalEmailId.Text + "','" + txtAlternativeContactPersonName.Text + "','" + txtWebsite.Text + "','" + txtClientClassification.Text + "','" + txtDetails.Text + "','" + txtGroup.Text + "','" + pictureBox1.Image + "')";



            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s, con);
            if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() >= 1)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Succesfully Updated !!");

            }
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            /*if(txtFaxNo.Text==""||txtMobileNo.Text==""||txtOffPhoneNo.Text=="")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Fax No,Mobile No,Office No should not be character");
            }*/
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

I want to access previous value of i which is stored in data table Add_Information even after the current form is closed

Answer (score 1):

I am agree with Adil But if you don't want to make

> Add_Information

identity write a stored procedure that return max value of

> Add_Infomation

from table and use it

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `Add_Information` a identity column and do not pass its value, the DBMS will automatically generate the incremented values for you. You can also query the database to get the max value of column `Add_Information`. If you store value in application then it could be available if form is closed but will be lost if application is closed.